# Cloudfoundry UAA preflight Origin header not allowed in Safari

Tags: ajax, safari, cloud-foundry, preflight, cloudfoundry-uaa

I'm trying to access the `Cloudfoundry UAA`service using `Ajax`.

My `POST` request to the `<uaa-url>/oauth/token` triggers a `preflight Options` request.

Which in `Chrome and firefox` sends following control header value

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization, content-type
```

It works fine as `UAA` allows these headers in `CORS` response.

Issue comes with `Safari` which includes a new header `Origin` in the control header as below (for `preflight Options` request)

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization, content-type, origin
```

In response to above request UAA sends `403` along with HTML body with message

```
<h1>HTTP Status 403 - Illegal header requested</h1>
```

I have omitted the irrelevant HTML.

My question is if UAA doesn't support `Origin` header in the `allowed CORS headers`, how is Safari ever going to make an Ajax request to the `UAA` service?

As safari is sending this `Origin` header in every preflight request. I'm lost here and considering now to make server side request to UAA.

**At this point it seems impossible to make an Ajax request to Cloudfoundry UAA instance using Safari browser.**

I've used `Password grant type` to implement custom login form with UAA. For which I'm using the Ajax so that application server doesn't know about the password.

Any suggestions to implement custom login form without sharing password with the server and without using Ajax are also welcome.

Comment: Can you post both the request and the response here. As well as any UAA configuration you may have added. Thanks

Comment: I will try to add some configuration details, however issue with `Origin` header does not occur for a specific configuration. You can try hitting any UAA service from Safari using Ajax, even the home page, you'll get `403` for preflight.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried configuring the headers you wish your UAA to accept using

```
cors:
  default:
    allowed:
      headers:
        - accept
        - authorization
        - content-type
        - origin
        - authorization
        - accept-language
        - content-language
```

Comment: I haven't, I didn't know that it was even possible. I'll try this, it looks promising. Where should this configuration be done ?